# Flood fill algorithm works slowly

Tags: opengl

I've got code for `flood fill` algorithm.

```
void floodFill() {
    float target[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    float border[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float clearp[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    std::stack<pixel*> colored;
    if (!stack.empty()) // stack contains first pixel
        colored.push(stack.top());

    while(!colored.empty()) {

        pixel *p = colored.top();
        drawPixel(p->x, p->y, target);
        colored.pop();

        //up
        float pix[3];
        glReadPixels(p->x, p->y + KOEF, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pix);
        if (!compare(pix,border) && compare(pix,clearp)) {
            pixel *pn = new pixel();
            pn->x = p->x;
            pn->y = p->y + KOEF;
            colored.push(pn);
        }
        //down
        glReadPixels(p->x, p->y - KOEF, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pix);
        if (!compare(pix,border) && compare(pix,clearp)) {
            pixel *pn = new pixel();
            pn->x = p->x;
            pn->y = p->y - KOEF;
            colored.push(pn);
        }

        //left
        glReadPixels(p->x - KOEF, p->y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pix);
        if (!compare(pix,border) && compare(pix,clearp)) {
            pixel *pn = new pixel();
            pn->x = p->x - KOEF;
            pn->y = p->y;
            colored.push(pn);
        }

        //right
        glReadPixels(p->x + KOEF, p->y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pix);
        if (!compare(pix,border) && compare(pix,clearp)) {
            pixel *pn = new pixel();
            pn->x = p->x + KOEF;
            pn->y = p->y;
            colored.push(pn);
        }

    }
}
```

I draw pixel using this method

```
void drawPixel(float x, float y, float *t) {
glRasterPos2i(x, y); 
glDrawPixels(1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, t);
for(int i = 0; i < KOEF; i++) {

    glRasterPos2i(x, y + i); 
    glDrawPixels(1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, t);

    glRasterPos2i(x + i, y); 
    glDrawPixels(1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, t);

    glRasterPos2i(x + i, y + i); 
    glDrawPixels(1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, t);
}
};
```

To fill some area I choose first pixel with mouse click and then call method `floodFill`.

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
    pixel *p = new pixel();
    p->x = x;
    p->y = HEIGHT - y;
    if (!stack.empty())
        stack.pop();
    stack.push(p); // first pixel

    floodFill();
}
};
```

The result is (for example)

[image]

But it works very slow(several seconds. area on the picture - it was drawing it for 11 seconds. area around letter - 43 seconds). And I thought it slowly will draw pixel after pixel but it is waiting for several seconds and then I see the result.

my pc is

```
intel core 2 duo p8600 2.4 GHz
nvidia 9600m gt 512 mb
windows x86 
ram 4 GB(3)`
```

Should it work so slow or there is a problem?

Comment: Did you try running your program under a profiler, like [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy)?

Comment: Not surprising, `glReadPixels (...)` is a round-trip operation and you are literally flooding OpenGL with single-pixel reads. OpenGL is based on a client/server architecture, you need to minimize the number of read-backs if you want decent performance. You would be better off doing this entirely on the CPU and then transferring your image to the OpenGL at the very end or at the very least reading more than one pixel at a time.

Comment: If you want to see the pixels being drawn one after another, you should swap the buffers inside your `while`

Comment: Furthermore, use of `GL_FLOAT` for the pixel transfer format increases driver overhead most of the time. I can say with a great deal of confidence that your window does not have a floating-point RGB pixel format, so the driver has to do data conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should it work so slow or there is a problem?

No, it should not.  Because Photoshop can make it faster :-)

It looks like there are some efficiency-related issues.

1. You should not use OpenGL calls for single pixel operations. You should better make a buffered copy of the image, process (floodfill) it, then copy back.
2. Why are you using these strange float coordinates instead of normal integer pixel indices?
   And what about not using floats for colors too? Floating point operations are slower than integer ones and float values needs further convesion to internal image format.
3. Your program seems to be too OOP-ish for its purpose. It is not good idea to use `new` and `stack` in the innermost loop of the image processing routine.

Answer (score 6):

That's a *terrible* way to use OpenGL.

Do your flood-fill in host memory, upload the resulting bitmap to an OpenGL texture, and then render a quad with that texture.

Comment: Too complicated. It my first task using OpenGL.

Comment: @user1432980 if that's to complicated then I'd suggest that you don't use OpenGL. Since this is the way that the OpenGL architecture suggest. If you use (or rather misuse) OpenGL in this way then you're just slowing things down. If you do not want to change your approach then change the library use SDL or something comparable (but that'll just delegate the uploading to the GPU to the OS)

Comment: The question is not whether I want it or not. And it's a task, not some serious application at all.`if it works - it works`.